# Setting style doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, css

Why does this script not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Hello StackOverflow!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="testing">
            <p>Bladybla</p>
        </div>
        <script>
            var one = window.innerWidth;
            var two = 5;
            var three = one / two;
            var four = '"' + Math.round(three) + "px" + '"';
            document.getElementById("testing").style.marginTop = four;
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

When I place an alert between `var four` and the `document.getElementById` is calculates the right value. The problem is in the `.style.marginTop =` . It doesn't print the calculated value. WHY?

Thanks in advance, Jaapyse!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var four = Math.round(three) + "px";
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WBPMd/1/)

Answer (score 5):

When you set .style.marginTop, you don't need to include quotes in your value.

If you were setting it to a hardcoded value, you might have:

```
document.getElementById("testing").style.marginTop = "5px";
```

However, you're effectively setting it to something like:

```
document.getElementById("testing").style.marginTop = '"5px"';
```

This is then an invalid value, so it gets ignored.

Change your code to this:

```
var one = window.innerWidth;
var two = 5;
var three = one / two;
var four = Math.round(three) + 'px';
document.getElementById("testing").style.marginTop = four;
```

Comment: **+1**  for the explanation about the problem with the `"`. Instead of just writing working code without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

write your script like :

```
<script>
                var one = window.innerWidth;
                var two = 5;
                var three = one / two;
                var four = Math.round(three);
                document.getElementById("testing").style.marginTop = four + 'px';
            </script>
```